# How to find this noncreasing function?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces,satisfies:
$\forall R>0,\exists \delta>0,d(x,x')<R\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(x'))<\delta.$

Then there exists a nondecreasing function $l:\mathbb{R^{+}}\to \mathbb{R^{+}}$ such that $d(f(x),f(x'))\leq l(d(x,x')).$

My try:
Let $\delta^{'}(R)=sup\{\delta(t)|t\leq R\}$,then $\delta^{'}$ is a nondecreasing function.Let $l=k\delta^{'}$ where k is a constant.But I can't find such k.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try
$$
l(R) = \sup\{d(f(x),f(x^\prime)) \ \vert\ d(x, x^\prime)\le R\}
$$